# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\Router::group(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\...php on the line 261 and exactly 2 expected

Tags: laravel

### My Route is this

> I tried using Guard method authentication and could not resolve it
> please help!! what could be the reason for these errors?
> If there is no specified content then please let me know.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin',function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard']);

}]);
```

here is the link where you can see through image
[My error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPUQi.png)

### My AdminController if needed

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Models\admin;
use Session;
use Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    public function makeLogin(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        if($validator -> fails()){
            return back()
                    -> withErrors($validator)
                    -> withInput();
        }

        $data = array(
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
        );
        
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($data)){
            return redirect('dashboard');
        }else{
            return back()->withErrors(['message' => 'invalid email or password']);
        }

    }

    public function dashboard(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot and add the callback function inside the `array` it should be the second parameter like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'],function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard']);

});
```

you could also write it like this

```
Route::middleware(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard']);

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Joseph. I didn't even recognize a small mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You should set only middleware in array.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'],function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard']);

});
```

Comment: I'm new to Laravel so it is being a little bit complex for me to find out the solution, and I learned new things today. Thank you @Josh.